# UDP broadcast in LabVIEW

Tags: sockets, udp, broadcast, labview

I have the following simple code implemented in LabVIEW for Windows PC.
[image]

Also, I have an app on another machine which sends 18-byte length UDP packages.

When the sender sends the package directly, everything works fine. I receive the correct package:

> 810A 0012 0120 FFFF 00FF 1008 0900 1B04 1EB0

Once I set the package to be broadcasted locally or globally I receive 25-byte length package. 60% of the package matches the reality, here it is:

> 810B 0019 0120 FFFF 00FF 1000 C402 0000 7B22 0400 9103 2201 04

I run the Wireshark and see that my network card receives a correct package for both cases (direct traffic or broadcast). So the problem is with my LabVIEW code or UDP read function in LabVIEW.

Did you have such an experience?

Comment: Update: Upon broadcast LabVIEW receives 2 packages. 1st is the right one, 2nd is the false one (25-byte length).

Comment: Update: Everything is fine when I close and open the UDP connection every iteration.

Comment: Sending Port and IP address of the wrong packet are correct? Is the source your app?

Comment: No, I just get the issue. There is another app sending the wrong one. So the scheme is the following. My app sends UDP broadcast. Other App sees the broadcast and replies with other Broadcast. The LabVIEW shows up the latest package, so I mistakenly thought there is an error. 

I think I solved the problem. Should I delete the question, or you can write an answer for others to prevent such a problem in the future.

Comment: Just wrote the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending Port and IP address of the wrong packet are correct? Is the source your app?

Maybe somebody else is sending the second packet.